# azure pipeline build does not getting triggered for other branches other than the pipeline branch

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-yaml

I am building a DevOps pipeline with azure-pipeline.yml with the **github** repository **repo1**. The pipeline **pipe1** is set to branch **dev2** of **repo1**. the structure of the azure-pipeline.yml in **dev2** branch as follows:

```
trigger:
- '*'
resources:
- repo: self

variables:
.....

pr: none //last line
```

There are 2 problems:

1. When i push a commit to **dev2** the pipeline gets triggered , but when i push a commit to any other branch ex  **dev3**. The pipeline does not get triggered.
2. Also when i push a commit to **master** branch it does not get triggered. The master branch does not have any **azure-pipeline.yml** file.

Can anyone tell me what is missing here and how can i correct that?

Comment: You mentioned 'but when i push a commit to any other branch ex dev3. The pipeline does not get triggered.', please make sure every branch you want to be triggerred has yml file that the pipeline needed there. :)

Comment: Make sure the branch you want to trigger has the required yml file, and go on.

Comment: @BowmanZhu-MSFT Thanks , i have a question here, in the pipeline pipe1 i have already set the branch to dev2 during its creation, dev2 has the latest version of the .yml file and the code needed is there, why its required to have a .yml file in dev3 has dev2 has the .yml file and will it not trigger the build for dev3 branch when i set trigger:
                    - '*'

Comment: Hi, in your situation, 'pipeline' concept on DevOps side will not monitor the commits in dev3 and master because no related .yml file there. See my answer. :)

Comment: Run DevOps yaml pipeline needs to based on related yml file, if no yml file on a branch, the pipeline will be unable to run on it. Also will not monitor the changes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your reply, seems dev3 branch and master branch both doesn't have the .yml file. If so, this problem is caused by incorrect conceptual understanding.

How the whole DevOps pipeline works:

For example, on my side, there are four branches on GitHub side(main, master, dev3,dev2; dev3 and master doesn't have .yml file.):

[image]

Edit the pipeline definition from DevOps pipeline:

[image]

This is the .yml file my pipeline is based on:

[image]

You can change the YAML file your pipeline based on via the follow steps:

[image]

[image]

Since my pipeline is based on azure-pipeline.yml, let see what will happen if the commit been submit to branch dev3 and master:

[image]

[image]

[image]

In this situation, I am using [CI trigger of GitHub](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/repos/github?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#ci-triggers), but this CI trigger only exists in main and dev2. Even my commits in dev3 and master been submitted, the pipeline will not monitor these commits.

'Pipeline' concept on DevOps side based on .yml file to monitor changes/commits. No .yml file, pipeline will not been triggered. And this .yml file must be the pipeline related to, otherwise the pipeline will also not monitor.